# cannot use setIcon method on the e.getComponent from a mouseListener

Tags: java, jlabel, mouselistener

I want to change the label's icon image after its being clicked

I add a mouseListener to my label and initialize with red_seat.jpg

```
String seatImageUrl = "red_seat.jpg";
tempL = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(seatImageUrl));
tempL.addMouseListener(new seatMouseEvent());
```

In my mouseListener class clicked method, I have

```
public class seatMouseEvent implements MouseListener{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        String seatImageUrl= "newImage.jpg";
        try{    
            e.getComponent().setIcon(new ImageIcon(seatImageUrl)); //setIcon it's undefined
        }   
        catch(Exception ex){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " +ex.getMessage() );
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to use cast

```
((JLabel)e.getComponent().)setIcon(new ImageIcon(seatImageUrl));
```